# Angular2 weird form behavior with *ngFor

Tags: arrays, angular, angular2-forms

Hey again for those who have seen my several posts about this form with the bottles... It's back again.

Before I start explaining anything, here is a **working plunkr** showing the issue :

**[Working Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/1z6dN6?p=preview)**

N.B : I'm displaying the Bottle `typeId` in the 2nd array, it shows the issue clearly.

---

**The issue :**

I was checking the bindings to make sure the values I was selecting were passed correctly, when I encountered an issue with the following scenario :

- 1 : Add some `Order` or `Return order` so that you have several inputs.
- 2 : Select some types and set some values in these inputs.
- 3 : If you remove any of the inputs that is NOT the last one of the Array, and then re-add an Input, the values are messed up even though the bindings to the ngModel are still correct.

Is there a way to avoid this weird behavior using standard `Template Driven Forms` ? Or do I have to go through `ReactiveForms` ?

---

**I'll explain here most of my code :**

I'm sending an Array of gas bottles (`bottleArray`) containing their `name` and `typeId` to my form as `@Input()`.

I deep clone this array and its objets into two separate arrays : `orderedClonedArrayBottles` and `returnedClonedArrayBottles`.

I then add values to my corresponding displayed arrays : `orderedBottles` and `returnedBottles` which have now a `count` value.

```
...
@Input() private bottleArray: Bottle[];

private orderedClonedArrayBottles: Bottle[] = [];
private returnedClonedArrayBottles: Bottle[] = [];
private orderedBottles: BottleCommand[] = [];
private returnedBottles: BottleCommand[] = [];

ngOnChanges(changes) {
  // Get @Input data when it's ready
  if (changes.bottleArray) {
    // Cloning the Array AND the Bottles
    this.orderedClonedArrayBottles = this.deepClone(changes.bottleArray.currentValue);
    this.returnedClonedArrayBottles = this.deepClone(changes.bottleArray.currentValue);

    // Display first rows
    if (this.orderedClonedArrayBottles.length > 0) {
      this.orderedBottles.push(this.orderedClonedArrayBottles[0]);
    }
    if (this.returnedClonedArrayBottles.length > 0) {
      this.returnedBottles.push(this.returnedClonedArrayBottles[0]);
    }
  }
}
```

I can delete any index of any Array with the following method :

```
removeRow(index: number, type: string, event: Event): void {
  event.stopPropagation();
  if (type == 'order') {
    // Cleans the reference 'count' value.
    this.orderedBottles[index].count = null;
    this.orderedBottles.splice(index, 1);
  } else {
    this.returnedBottles[index].count = null;
    this.returnedBottles.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

I can push items in any of these 2 arrays with 2 separate buttons : `AddOrder()` and `AddReturnOrder()` (same code) :

```
addOrder(event: Event): void {
  event.stopPropagation();
  // Limits to the number of types
  if (this.orderedBottles.length < this.orderedClonedArrayBottles.length) {
    let index = this.getAvailableIndex(this.orderedBottles, this.orderedClonedArrayBottles);
    this.orderedBottles.push(this.orderedClonedArrayBottles[index]);
  }
}
```

To avoid pushing an existing reference in my arrays, I use the following method that will get me the first available index that is not already displayed :

```
/**
 * Gets the first available index from 2 arrays containing the same references.
 *
 * @param {Object[]} displayedArray Array containing the occupied indexes
 * @param {Object[]} referenceArray Array containing all the indexes
 * @return {number} Index of the first available position
 */
getAvailableIndex(displayedArray: Object[], referenceArray: Object[]): number {
  let index: number = null;
  // Gets the available indexes of Bottles by filtering the referenceArray with the displayedArray
  let availablePositions: Object[] = referenceArray.filter(element => displayedArray.indexOf(element) < 0);
  // Return the first position available
  return index = referenceArray.indexOf(availablePositions[0]);
}
```

**Here is the corresponding HTML :** (clearer in Plunkr)

```
  <div fxLayout="row" style="max-width: 80%">
    <div fxLayout="column" style="min-width: 50%">

      <div fxLayout="row" style="max-width: 100%" *ngFor="let bottle of orderedBottles; let i = index">
        <md-select class="select" placeholder="Select bottle type" name="orderedTypeSelect_{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="orderedBottles[i].typeId">
          <md-option class="options" *ngFor="let type of bottleArray" [value]="type.typeId">
            {{ type.name }}
          </md-option>
        </md-select>

        <md-input-container class="container">
          <input md-input type="number" name="orderedBottleInput_{{i}}" autocomplete="off" [(ngModel)]="orderedBottles[i].count"
          step="1" min="0" max="99">
        </md-input-container>

        <button class="button-row" type="button" (click)="removeRow(i, 'order', $event)">-</button>

        {{orderedBottles[i].typeId}} -
        {{orderedBottles[i].count}}
      </div>

    </div>


    <div fxLayout="column" style="min-width: 50%">

      <div fxLayout="row" style="max-width: 100%" *ngFor="let bottle of returnedBottles; let j = index">
        <md-select class="select" placeholder="Select bottle type" name="returnedTypeSelect_{{j}}" [(ngModel)]="returnedBottles[j].typeId">
          <md-option class="options" *ngFor="let type of bottleArray; let z = index" [value]="bottleArray[z].typeId">
            {{ bottleArray[z].typeId }}
          </md-option>
        </md-select>

        <md-input-container class="container">
          <input md-input type="number" name="returnedBottleInput_{{j}}" autocomplete="off" [(ngModel)]="returnedBottles[j].count"
          step="1" min="0" max="99">
        </md-input-container>

        <button style="margin-top: -20px;" class="button-row" type="button" (click)="removeRow(j, 'return', $event)">-</button>

        {{returnedBottles[j].typeId}} -
        {{returnedBottles[j].count}}
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="margin">
    <button md-raised-button type="button" class="submit-button" (click)="addOrder($event)">Add Order</button>
    <button md-raised-button type="button" class="submit-button" (click)="addReturnOrder($event)">Add Return Order</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `trackBy` to avoid mess:

```
*ngFor="let bottle of orderedBottles; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn"

trackByFn(index) {
    return index;
}
```

It also improves your performance

**[Modified Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TO3tHc?p=preview)**

See also

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngfortrackby

Comment: Damn it was that simple... Thanks !